# Side edging for hexagonal stone pavers? Concrete ok?

Tags: driveway, paving

I have an idea for a walkway or driveway that would be surface with thick hexagonal pavers.

One of the challenges of this design is that the edge of the paving will be irregular, since each tile is hexagonal:

[image]

So, one thought I had is to use concrete. I would build a form around the edges of the paving and pour concrete to secure the sides and produce a straight edge to the road or walkway.

My concern is that the concrete might be incompatible with the stone in some way. For example, it might contract and expand at a different rate.

What are risks here? I want to avoid a situation where the edging is cracking and falling apart in 10 or 20 years.

Comment: You don't want to just cut some hexagons in half and get a straight edge that way?  You get two edge pieces with one cut.

Answer (score 2):

Expansion isn't really a concern. Finishing the edge is. You can't just screed the slab to the pavers and expect a good outcome. You'd have to edge the slab along each angle of the pavers' shape to eliminate the sharp corner. You can imagine how tedious that would be.

Also, you'll have staining on the surface of your pavers unless you protect them somehow or acid wash it later.

Like JPhi1618 said, [halving pavers to create a straight line](http://www.historicpavement.com/hexagonal-sidewalk-pavers) is the usual approach. A 7" angle grinder with a serrated diamond blade works well, or rent a wet saw.

Comment: Interesting to see that so many of the images at that link have a combination of halved pavers and a rectangular stone on the sides to make a border.  And since those are "historic", they were obviously built well and have lasted decades.

Comment: Yeah, that's often done to eliminate the occurrence of small paver pieces at the edges, for stability, as well as for aesthetics.